# Reading individual files from a tar of subprocess' stdout

Tags: python

How could I read individual files' contents from a commands' stdout without hitting the disk?

I've come up with something like this:

```
def get_files_from(sha, files):
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    import tarfile
    p = Popen(["git", "archive", sha], bufsize=10240, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=p.stdout, mode='r|')
    p.communicate()
    members = tar.getmembers()
    names = tar.getnames()
    contents = {}
    for fname in files:
        if fname not in names:
            contents[fname] = None
            continue
        else:
            idx = names.index(fname)
            contents[fname] = members[idx].tobuf()
            contents[fname] = tar.extractfile(members[idx]) #<--- HERE

    tar.close()
    return contents
```

The problem is that adding a `.read()` call on the line marked

```
            contents[fname] = tar.extractfile(members[idx]) #<--- HERE
```

will give the error:

> tarfile.StreamError: seeking backwards is not allowed

So how to get the contents of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misspelled your `mode=` parameter, you wrote `more=` instead:

```
tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=p.stdout, mode='r|')
```

`.tell()` won't be called if you specify the mode correctly. :-)

You'll then have to *loop over* the tarfile object to extract the members, you cannot read arbitrary files from the tarfile:

```
for entry in tar:
    # test if this is a file you want.
    if entry.name in files:
        f = tar.extractfile(entry)
```

You cannot use any of the `.getnames()`, `.getmember()` or `.getmembers()` methods as these require a full scan of the file, putting the file pointer at the end and leaving you without a means to read the entry data itself.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me further. However ... please see my update, it doesn't work...

Comment: @Flavius: note that it isn't really good practice changing your question to solve each new problem you encounter. I solved your initial problem, for example. It's hard to vote for answers to changing questions.

Comment: Should I create a new question with the same title? It's still the same problem. And I've upvoted your answer already...

Comment: I've already updated my answer, just pointing out that *next* time you may want to create a new question. :-)

Comment: It gives the same error: `    for entry in tar:
        print entry
        contents[entry.name] = tar.extractfile(entry).read()
`

Comment: Should I really open the tar file twice, as `tar` and `tf`?

Comment: Oh, the calls to `getmembers()` and `getnames()` were messing with the cursor (logically!). Thanks, got it working. I'd like to post the final, working code, how should I proceed? I'll accept your answer, but should I post the code as an answer, or in the question?

Comment: @Flavius: Finilized my answer, no need to add an extra answer with how your code is now working. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's interested:

```
def get_files_from(sha, files):
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    import tarfile
    p = Popen(["git", "archive", sha], bufsize=10240, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=p.stdout, mode='r|')
    p.communicate()
    contents = {}
    doall = files == '*'
    if not doall:
        files = set(files)
    for entry in tar:
        if (isinstance(files, set) and entry.name in files) or doall:
            tf = tar.extractfile(entry)
            contents[entry.name] = tf.read()
            if not doall:
                files.discard(entry.name)

    if not doall:
        for fname in files:
            contents[fname] = None

    tar.close()
    return contents

print get_files_from("a8c11fcee68881dfb86095aa36290fb304047cf1", ['README.MD', 'foo'])
print get_files_from("a8c11fcee68881dfb86095aa36290fb304047cf1", '*')
```

Patches welcome!